# H2 database - How to access function created in another alias

Tags: function, alias, h2

I am trying to replicate our database in H2 for testing purpose. I would like to create 2 functions and one of them depends on the other. The following codes are for oracle :

GET_FULL_ADDRESS:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "GET_FULL_ADDRESS"
(
    flat IN VARCHAR2,
    street IN VARCHAR2,
    district IN VARCHAR2,
    country_code IN VARCHAR2
)
RETURN VARCHAR2
IS
BEGIN
    RETURN flat || ', ' || street || ', ' || district || ', ' || CONVERT_COUNTRY_CODE(country_code);
END;
```

CONVERT_COUNTRY_CODE:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "CONVERT_COUNTRY_CODE"
(
    country_code IN VARCHAR2
)
RETURN VARCHAR2
IS
BEGIN
    CASE country_code
        WHEN 'UK' THEN RETURN 'United Kingdom';
        WHEN 'US' THEN RETURN 'United States';
        -- Skipping the rest of the cases...
        ELSE RETURN country_code;
    END CASE;
END;
```

I tried to convert them for H2 with ALIAS

GET_FULL_ADDRESS:

```sql
CREATE ALIAS GET_FULL_ADDRESS AS '
    String getFullAddress(String flat, String street, String district, String country_code) {
        return flat + ", " + street + ", " + district + ", " + convertCountryCode(country_code);
    }
';
```

CONVERT_COUNTRY_CODE:

```sql
CREATE ALIAS CONVERT_COUNTRY_CODE AS '
    String convertCountryCode(String country_code) {
        switch(country_code) {
            case "UK": return "United Kingdom";
            case "US": return "United States";
            // Skipping the rest of the cases...
            default: return country_code;
        }
    }
';
```

The above codes produce a "cannot find symbol" error

```
    convertCountryCode(country_code);
    ^
symbol:   method convertCountryCode(String)
location: class GET_FULL_ADDRESS
```

If I put the 2 functions into a single CREATE ALIAS statement it works, but both functions are referenced in my views so I need separated CREATE ALIAS statement.

How can I call the function defined in other CREATE ALIAS statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two possible approaches.

1. You can call another alias from the SQL code.

```sql
CREATE ALIAS CONVERT_COUNTRY_CODE AS '
    String convertCountryCode(String country_code) {
        switch(country_code) {
            case "UK": return "United Kingdom";
            case "US": return "United States";
            // Skipping the rest of the cases...
            default: return country_code;
        }
    }
';

CREATE ALIAS GET_FULL_ADDRESS AS '
    String getFullAddress(Connection conn, String flat, String street, String district, String country_code)
            throws SQLException {
        PreparedStatement prep = conn.prepareStatement("CALL CONVERT_COUNTRY_CODE(?)");
        prep.setString(1, country_code);
        ResultSet rs = prep.executeQuery();
        rs.next();
        return flat + ", " + street + ", " + district + ", " + rs.getString(1);
    }
';
```

2. If you can add Java classes to the classpath (or classpath of H2 Server process if you use the client-server model), you can define both functions as a normal Java code and call another method directly.

```java
package test;

public class CustomFunctions {

    public static String convertCountryCode(String country_code) {
        switch(country_code) {
            case "UK": return "United Kingdom";
            case "US": return "United States";
            // Skipping the rest of the cases...
            default: return country_code;
        }
    }

    public static String getFullAddress(String flat, String street, String district, String country_code) {
        return flat + ", " + street + ", " + district + ", " + convertCountryCode(country_code);
    }

}
```

```sql
CREATE ALIAS CONVERT_COUNTRY_CODE FOR "test.CustomFunctions.convertCountryCode";
CREATE ALIAS GET_FULL_ADDRESS FOR "test.CustomFunctions.getFullAddress";
```

Comment: About your first approach, I can see that you added "Connection conn" to the parameter list.

How do I pass a Connection to the function when calling it?

Comment: User-defined functions in H2 may have an optional Connection as a first argument. This connection is passed by H2, you shouldn't care about it. `SELECT GET_FULL_ADDRESS('flat', 'street', 'district', 'UK');` will work in both cases.